# Integral $\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{x}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

The integal is 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{x}~dx$$

My opnion is use fundamental theorem of calculus, calculate $F(x)$ and then use $F(1^-)-F(0^+)$.

But i cannot find the undetermined integral of $\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$.

Comment: Please, use $\LaTeX$ on posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the maclaurin series of $\ln{(1-x)}$:

$$I=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{x^n}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \; dx$$

By Fubini theorem, we can interchange the integral and summation:
$$I=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{n} \; dx$$
$$I= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^n}{n^2} \bigg \rvert_0^1$$
$$I= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: appreciate for that, but the module i learned didn't cover mclaurin seires or fubuni theorem, can you give me some other solutions? by the way , i think may be we can show ln(1-x)/x is converge ( not sure yet) , then use a Fourier Seires Sum  to subsititute it, then use this partial sum to calculate.

Comment: You know Fourier series but not Maclaurin (aka Taylor) series?

Comment: ahh,sorry for that, i forgot it has name mclaurin.